# use-ajax class doesn't trigger ajax event

Tags: ajax

This is part of my code in custom module in src/Plugin/Block/FavoriteBlock.php:

```
$build['ajax_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => $this->npxFavoritesRepository->getTitle($node),
  '#attached' => ['library' => ['npx_favorites/npx_favorites-library']],
  '#attributes' => ['class' => $classes],
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('npx_favorites.ajax_link_callback', ['node' => $node->id()]),
];
```

And it results with output, that is fine, but it doesn't trigger the AJAX event:

```
<a href="/pl/favorite/1045/toggle" data-once="ajax" class="use-ajax n-favourite favorite-1045 active">Usuń z ulubionych</a>
```

So when I click on that it brings me to page that looks like that:

[image: ajaxpageresult]

I have also another 'use-ajax' class from VUE template on the same page and it triggers the AJAX event. How can I make sure it is triggered, when I render this link from block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that VUE had conflicts with Ajax script.

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching the `drupal.ajax` library.

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.ajax';
```

Comment: I have this included, but it doesn't work